# Swift Package Manager: Avoid Unnecessary Sub-dependencies

Tags: swift-package-manager

I've got a SPM-based library with a dependency on a data parsing library. The library has a basic product that has the files I want, but also a few alternate products that has integrations with AlamoFire and RxSwift. The package declares dependencies on those two packages, which I have no interest in. Even though I'm only declaring a dependency on the basic product (which doesn't need AlamoFire and RxSwift), they still get pulled during the package resolution phase and clutter up the Package Dependency area. Any idea how to set up my package up so that the unnecessary sub-dependencies don't get pulled in?